# Create HTML Table by looping in Grid View ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have Grid view data like this

Machine Code |   Job     |  Worker  |   Start    |   End

```
DR01     |   AAA01   |   Mr.A   | 2017/01/01 | 2017/01/03
DR01     |   AAA02   |   Mr.B   | 2017/01/02 | 2017/01/04
DR01     |   AAA03   |   Mr.C   | 2017/01/03 | 2017/01/05
```

And I want to loop in grid view and show result like this

[DR01 Machine]

```
         |     AA01   |     AA02   |    AA03    |
         |     Mr.A   |     Mr.B   |    Mr.C    |
         | 2017/01/01 | 2017/01/02 | 2017/01/03 |
         | 2017/01/03 | 2017/01/04 | 2017/01/05 |
```

Comment: Better loop the source data. The GridView will format the dates as string. Converting them back could be tricky.

Comment: As said by @VDWWD: You should use data source to return expected result. More over seeing up your requirement you will end up creating a complex query. Here, you have to first use group by to show result in term of Machine Code and then you will loop in such a way that all your row based result will transform into column based.